# comparar año, mes y día en oracle

Tags: oracle

estoy trabajando en una consulta con filtros por mes, por año y día pero dicha consulta se queda  ejecutandose por mas de una hora y no  muestra información  lo que estoy haciendo en la consulta es lo siguiete:

```
select * from tabla1 where extract(year FROM fecha)=2020 
    and EXTRACT(MONTH from fecha)=4 
    and extract(day from fecha)< 17
```

no quieren que utilice un between

Comment: Esas condiciones, sobre una tabla con un número importante de millones, serán muy lentas. Mira: en cada condición del where aplicas una función sobre el campo fecha y lo validas, **por cada registro**. Podrías rediseñar la consulta haciendo una subconsulta que sirva _como una vista_ (con campos adicionales del año, el mes y el día) y sobre ella, hacer un where mucho más limpio donde el valor en esas columnas sea mayor a algún número, etc

Comment: El campo fecha lo tienes indexado?

Answer (score 1):

Una forma más simple (con dos condiciones, y sin operar en el campo `fecha`) de hacer lo mismo en el caso específico que indica tu consulta sería:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tabla1
WHERE fecha >= TRUNC(TO_DATE('17/04/2020', 'DD/MM/YYYY'),'MON') 
    AND fecha <= TO_DATE('17/04/2020', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
```

Si quieres ver por mes, o por año, o por día (que es diferente a lo que indicas en tu ejemplo), usarías:

```
SELECT *
FROM tabla1
WHERE TRUNC(fecha,'MON') = TO_DATE('01/01/2020', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
```

'MON' es para mes, pero lo puedes cambiar por 'YYYY' o sin parámetro (`trunc(fecha)`) para año o día, respectivamente.

Como adicional, yo puse las fechas en formado dd/mm/yyyy porque mi dbms lo tiene configurado así. Dependiendo del que tengas puede que sea diferente o necesite máscara de formato.

Comment: al usar TO_DATE es mejor siempre usar el parámetro de formato para evitar conversiones errradas

Comment: Cierto, sorry, la mala costumbre! Le añadí la máscara